# Firebase Cloud Function Got error The request was aborted because there was no available instance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

From March 31, I start getting errors on Firebase Cloud Function console.(Region: asia-east1)

The request was aborted because there was no available instance. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability

I've tried "functions.region('asia-east1').runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 180, memory: '256MB', minInstances: 1 })" ,but it's still got this errors from time to time.

Also, the errors only show on my test projects, not the production. I don't change much code at least not all the cloud functions. But it happened on every cloud function. I've tried many ways but still have no idea how it happened.

Does someone have the problem as well or know how to fix it? Thanks

---

This is the whole error log, and the error doesn't show just on this function, it could happen on any cloud function.

[image]

Also, My production(release version) on google/apple store have no error, but my test project got many, the difference is that the production(release version) calls functions on mobile devices, and the test project calls functions from unity editor.

I am not sure if it matters, and I still keep testing.

Comment: Can you please specify the error and some more details from logs?

Comment: This is the whole error log:  
The request was aborted because there was no available instance. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability

Comment: I don't change the code for this issue, but it hasn't happened now.